# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Employee` with those columns

```
empid, empname, job, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno
```

I want to verify if this is correct:

1. Number of employees in each department
2. How many people there are in each type of job in each department
3. Display the department and number of employees in department with fewer than 6 employees
4. Find the employee name and its salary who is earning maximum salary in dept 20

Here is what I have tried:

Query #1:

```
select DEPTNO, count(*) AS NO_OF_PERSONS 
from EMP 
group by DEPTNO;
```

Query #2:

```
select job, count(*) AS NO_OF_PERSONS 
from EMP 
group by job;
```

Query #3:

```
update EMPLOYEE 
set sal = sal + 1000 
where com > 2500;
```

And I am unable to do the 4th part.

Comment: Please , show sample data (as text) and expectes result

Comment: Please include what you've tried for part 4.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that below queries will help you.

> 1. no of employees in each dept?

```
SELECT DEPTNO,
       count(*) AS NO_OF_PERSONS
FROM EMP
GROUP BY DEPTNO;
```

> 2. how many people are there in each type of job in each department?

```
SELECT job,
       deptno,
       count(*) AS NO_OF_PERSONS
FROM EMP
GROUP BY job,
         deptno;
```

> 3. display the department and no of employees in department with fewer than 6 employee.

```
SELECT deptno,
       count(*)
FROM emp
GROUP BY deptno
HAVING count(*) < 6;
```

> 4. find the employee name and its salary who is earning maximum salary in dept 20.

```
SELECT Max(salary_amount),
       empid
FROM EMP
WHERE deptno = 20
GROUP BY empid;
```

You can start learning Basic SQL [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: In the last example you need to swap the WHERE and GROUP BY terms.

Comment: @Dan, The result generated will be the same in both cases, because WHERE is executed before aggregation in any case.

Comment: if you put the WHERE after the GROUP BY you get an `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` error.

Comment: @Dan, my bad. some RDMS doesn't support where after GROUP BY. thanks for pointing out :-)

Comment: No problem. Good answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.name, e1.sal 
  from EMP e1
 where e1.DEPTNO = 20 
   and not exists(select *
                    from EMP e2
                   where e2.DEPTNO = 20
                     and e2.sal > e1.sal);
```